# How to prevent password visible while get user data from MYSQL with Nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I would like show details except password remaining data. It work while getbyid by using particular userid, But it is working get all data from table. Here i am attached 2 screenshot one is get data using by id, another is get all user data from table.

I need result as well getbyid.

following getbyId code work properly

```
exports.getOneUserListById = async (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  try {
    dbConfig.query(
      `SELECT * FROM communityabstract WHERE id="${id}"`,
      (err, rows) => {
        const {password,...data}=rows[0]

        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ status: "Failed", message: err });
        }
        if(rows.length===0){ res.status(404).json({status:"No data available"})}else{
        res.json({ status: "Success", result: data });}
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ status: "Failed", message: err });
  }
};
```

[image: I don't want show password value][image: This is working properly.I expect same result in getall data]

Below Code not gave me expected result

```
exports.getAllUserList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    dbConfig.query(`SELECT * FROM communityabstract`, (err, rows) => {
      const {password,...data}=rows
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ status: "Failed", message: err });
      }
      res.json({ status: "Success", result: data });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ status: "Failed", message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: Exclude the password from the sql query. BTW: You should not store the password in plain text in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you.

```
exports.getAllUserList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    dbConfig.query(`SELECT * FROM communityabstract`, (err, rows) => {
const {password,...data}=rows
      data.password = undefined;
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ status: "Failed", message: err });
      }
      res.json({ status: "Success", result: data });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ status: "Failed", message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: I found answer.               const result = rows.map(({ password, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest }));